# UFD is also an ideal of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, complex-geometry, unique-factorization-domains

Is it true that when a UFD is another ring $R$'s ideal, then ring $R$ is also a UFD?

I find an example but I'm not sure: the holomorphic ring $\mathcal O_x$, it's a UFD and the meromorphic ring $\mathcal M_x$, it's also a UFD (I guess but I'm not sure).

Comment: Holomorphic functions do not form an ideal but a subring of meromorphic functions. Meromorphic functions form a field, so it is a UFD for trivial reasons.

Comment: If you were thinking *subring* instead of *ideal*, consider $ℤ$ within any domain of characterisitc null that’s not a unique factorization domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ideal shared identity with the containing ring, then trivially yes, since an ideal containing the identity is the entire ring.

If it is an ideal with a different identity, then no because the identity is a nontrivial idempotent, and domains don’t have nontrivial idempotents.